# default checkbox value could not unchecked in jq grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

when i try to unchecked default  value of  check box   but not success,

My code is:

```
colModel: [
                { name: 'CanDelete', width: 50, index: 'CanDelete', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "Yes:No:",defaultValue: "No" }, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false} 
},
```

My jq grid version is 4.1.2,
i am   trying to do.
checkbox is still checked!!!

Comment: You should describe the problem more clear. It's unclear for me why you use **both** editing **and** `formatoptions: { disabled: false}`. I think you should **remove the `formatoptions`**. In any way you should describe the problem more details. By the way I see no reason to use very old version of jqGrid. I would recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) with many new features (see [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). You current problem is not dependent from it directly.

Comment: Please do not use the [[tag:jq]] tag for [_[tag:jquery]_] questions, they are not the same...